# Mysql error when using Cake Bake

Tags: cakephp

H,
  I am a newbie to cake php. So there is a problem i'm facing with.

I have installed XAMPP and my cakephp project  folder lies in htdocs(/opt/lampp/htdocs/cakephp). When I start cake bake by the command /.cake bake, I am getting a mysql error as below.

```
enter code here

PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/cakephp/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 552
```

can u help me?

Comment: What does your config/database.php file say?

Comment: class DATABASE_CONFIG {

 var $default = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'persistent' => false,
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'login' => 'root',
  'password' => '',
  'database' => 'cake_blog_tutorial',
  'prefix' => '',
 );} This is the content in database.php in config folder

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have MySQL installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

With XAMPP normally get this error.

You can do two things to solve it:

1. A clean installation of Apache + PHP + MySQL
2. If you're on a linux or on a mac you can create a symbolic link to the socket:

   ```
   ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
   ```

Where /tmp/ is your XAMPP mysql folder (e.g. /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock)